# New column to a dataframe picked up with "get"

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have difficulty adding a column to a dataframe that I have picked up with

```
get
```

The situation is similar to

```
V1<-c(1,2,3,4)
V2<-c(5,6,7,8)
V3<-c(9,10,11,12)
V4<-c(13,14,15,16)

df1<-data.frame(V1,V2)
df2<-data.frame(V2,V3)
Names<-c("df1","df2")
```

Why does

```
for(i in 1:2){get(Names[i])$new.col<-V4}
```

return

```
Error in get(Names[i])$new.col <- V4 : could not find function "get<-"
```

and not just --- work fine? Any hint on how to improve will (also) be very much appreciated.

Comment: My recommendation is to simply ban `get` from your lexicon entirely. It encourages programming patterns that are quite bad (like the answer you seem to approve of below). Learn to use lists before you start resorting to things like `get`.

Comment: Thx. I do work with lists. Yet, in trying out several means to the same cause I came across this problem with "get" and was wondering why it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your example is subset of something more complex, where you really need to get the objects from some environment, it usually works better to use a construct like `.GlobalEnv[[Names[i]]]$new.col<-V4`
 instead of `get()`. With `get()` you would need to assign the printed object first to an object, and then probably with `assign()` push it back to a correctly named object. The solution using a list might be even better, though.

By the way, is there a reason why you cannot modify the object directly or use a list?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a number of data frames and want to do the same operation to each, you could store them in a list and operate on each element using `lapply`. For your example that could be done as follows:

```
lst <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

lst
#$df1
#  V1 V2
#1  1  5
#2  2  6
#3  3  7
#4  4  8
#
#$df2
#  V2 V3
#1  5  9
#2  6 10
#3  7 11
#4  8 12
```

Then, to add `V4` as a column named "new.col" to each element:

```
lapply(lst, function(df) cbind(df, new.col = V4))
#$df1
#  V1 V2 new.col
#1  1  5      13
#2  2  6      14
#3  3  7      15
#4  4  8      16
#
#$df2
#  V2 V3 new.col
#1  5  9      13
#2  6 10      14
#3  7 11      15
#4  8 12      16
```

This would be more R-idiomatic than using a for-loop.

Edit: another approach, as commented by @DavidArenburg (thanks btw), is using `Map`:

```
Map(cbind, lst, new.col = list(V4))
#$df1
#  V1 V2 new.col
#1  1  5      13
#2  2  6      14
#3  3  7      15
#4  4  8      16
#
#$df2
#  V2 V3 new.col
#1  5  9      13
#2  6 10      14
#3  7 11      15
#4  8 12      16
```

Comment: Thx. I do work with lists. However, in trying something different I came across this problem and was wondering why it occurs. Also, in my real setting I am not attaching the same V4 to all columns.